# How to fix 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library' Export Excel to PDF using PHPExcel TCPDF

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, pdf, phpexcel

I want to export my Excel to PDF file using TCPDF in PHPExcel and save it to the path, but I found this error 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library'. Please help, how to fix this?

I'm not sure this is because of rendererLibraryPath

```
        $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $excel2 = $excel2->load('./template/invoice.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
        $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', $row['nama'])
            ->setCellValue('C7', $row['idpel'].$row['periode_tagihan'])
            ->setCellValue('H6', $row['idpel'])
            ->setCellValue('C6', $row['nama'])
            ->setCellValue('H7', $row['rekening_bulan'])
            ->setCellValue('H8', $row['tarif'])
            ->setCellValue('J8', $row['daya'])
            ->setCellValue('E12', $row['rpptl'])
            ->setCellValue('E13', $row['rpbpju'])
            ->setCellValue('E14', $row['rpppn'])
            ->setCellValue('E15', $row['rpmat'])
            ->setCellValue('E16', $row['tagsus'])
            ->setCellValue('E17', $row['rpbk'])
            ->setCellValue('E19', $row['rptottag'])
            ->setCellValue('C22', $terbilang)
            ->setCellValue('E25', $row['batas_akhir_bayar'])
            ->setCellValue('H33', date('d F Y'));

        //$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
        //$objWriter->save("./template/cetak/".$row['idpel'].$row['periode_tagihan'].".xlsx");

        $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
        $rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf';
        $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $rendererLibrary;
        PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $rendererLibraryPath);
        $path = "./template/cetak/".$row['idpel'].$row['periode_tagihan'].".pdf";
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($excel2);
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'PDF');
        $objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
        $objWriter->save($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

*** Remove TCPDF folder from vendor and install again with php composer.phar ***

[Hope this link help to find your solution](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export/issues/217)